# Search is slow in Node Mongo API?

Tags: mongodb, performance, mongodb-query, find, aggregate

I have created an API to search documents in Mongodb.
**As in my Mongodb there is More than 60 Millions Documents.**
So, I have created an API to search and the code is

```
let regexexp = new RegExp(searchquery.split('').join('\\s*'),'i');
s = {"name": regexexp, "status": 'AVAILABLE'};
db.collection(collectionName).find(s).count().then(function(totalcount) {
db.collection(collectionName).find(s).limit(18).toArray(function(err, res) {
  if (err) throw err;
  responsedata = { status: true,error : false,data : res,'totalproductcount': 
  totalcount};
  resolve(responsedata);
});
});
```

But it will take time around 1 min 30 sec sometimes 2 min to search 18 documents which is very much for any user is there anything which i have not used in it.

I have used these value for mongo db connction

```
const option = {
useUnifiedTopology: true,
useNewUrlParser: true,
socketTimeoutMS: 300000,
poolSize:500,
keepAlive: 300000,
connectTimeoutMS: 300000,
authSource:'admin',
};
```

Then i found out aggregation in Mongodb I have prepared query for that

```
db.collection('customers').aggregate( [ { $match: { name: "abc" } } ] 
).toArray(function(err, results) {
 console.log(results);
});
```

But it will only work for exact match i want to work if in name parameter is abc is present anywhere it will search that option but it doesn't work.

Is there any way to get the data in minimum time like i have checked from mongo shell it gives me data in milliseconds but it will take time when i hit it with my API.

If Any thing more required please posted here.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Unanchored regular expressions are not serviced by an index, so they require scanning the entire collection for every query.  Will the partial matches be along word/whitespace boundaries?

Comment: Thanks for your response @Joe yes it will be search with small character word and white-spaces too if i am correct understand.

Comment: You might try a text index for word-like searches with stemming.

Comment: Thanks for you concern actually  have found that my db.collection(collectionName).find(s).count().then(function(totalcount) that count query is taking time so will you please suggest anything here or i have asked a different question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68087938/how-to-optimise-find-count-query-using-mongodb-and-node?noredirect=1#comment120342265_68087938 please take a look and help.

Comment: Because the regex can't use an index, it will take as long as the find since it needs to examine all of the documents.