# How to optimise .find .count query using Mongodb and Node?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, performance, optimization, find

I have created an API to get the count of documents using Mongodb and Node.

Query is

```
var searchquery = 'ABC';
let regexexp = new RegExp(searchquery.split('').join('\\s*'),'i');
s = {"name": regexexp, "status": 'AVAILABLE'};

db.collection(collectionName).find(s).count().then(function(totalcount) {
    console.log(totalcount);
});
```

It is taking around 1 min to get the count result from 60 million records.
How to get that data in minimum time around 1-2 sec.

Is there anything which i have missed or used wrong?

Comment: create a compound index `{ name: 1, status: 1 }` and use `countDocuments` method instead of find and count methods.

Comment: Thanks for the response @turivishal have created index for that and will you please tell me how to use countDocuments with same regex.

Comment: see [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.countDocuments/). just pass your query in first parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the Link Actually i have been searching in db which has around 60 Million data  will it be that good ?

Comment: I have checked with the countDocuments it still takes same 1 min on postman with 60 Million data in mongodb
Will you please suggest or gave any other idea it will be very helpfull.

Comment: regular expression will not perform well, try to avoid that, or put a more filter, yes definitely 60 million data is not good, try to separate it to different collections categorize date / year / month wise or any other type field wise.